# Paper_Trail: Show Diff Between Versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, versions, paper-trail-gem

I'm new to Rails...using RubyMine as an IDE.

I have Paper_Trail saving previous versions of the data "xoi_qb". My view is currently showing the current and previous data as I'd like, but I would like to show the diff between the current version "xoi_qb" and the previous version "xoi_qb". For instance, the current version may be "97" and the previous version may be "94", and I would like to display "XOI +/-: +3". I would like to display this difference and add the "+" or "-" based on the positive or negative change.

In my model, Paper Trail is set to create versions like this:

```
  def get_xoi_qb
    xoi_qb = []
    self.versions.each do |version|
      unless version.reify.nil?
        xoi_qb << version.reify.xoi_qb
      end
    end
    return xoi_qb
  end
```

And in my HTML set to display the versions like this:

```
  <th>Previous XOI</th>
  <table>
    <% @quarterback.versions.each do |version| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= version.reify.xoi_qb %> dated <%= version.created_at %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Not sure how to show the difference between the two.

Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you want to display the difference between last version and current version record?

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [the documentation on diffing versions with PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#3c-diffing-versions). In particular, here's what you want to take note of:

If you add an **object_changes** text column to your **versions** table, either at installation time with the **rails generate paper_trail:install --with-changes** option or manually, PaperTrail will store the changes diff (excluding any attributes PaperTrail is ignoring) in each update version.

With this behavior enabled, it is reasonably simple to get **object.versions.map{|v| [v.created_at, v.changeset]}** and then iterate over that structure to render your change log.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you have installed paper_trail gem.
You can add an object_changes text column to your versions table either manually or through migration.

```
rails g migration AddColumnToVersions
class AddColumnToVersions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute "ALTER TABLE versions ADD object_changes TEXT"
  end
end
```

Then restart the server. Create the records.

Check the difference between last version and current version

```
@quarterback.versions.last.changeset
```

You can get the difference.

Source: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail - Diffing Versions

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Yes, definitely installed paper_gem...the versioning is working for me. I restarted the server. What do you mean by "crate"?

Does the @quarterback.versions.last.changeset just go in the html file? For instance:   
'<tr>
     <th>XOI +/-</th>
      <td><%= quarterback.versions.last.changeset %></td>
</tr>'

Comment: Im assuming quarterback is your table name.. So after restart the server, create one more record.(i.e) Ex: Quarterback.create(name: 'test') depends on your table. Then try, Quarterback.last.versions.last.changeset

Comment: I'm sorry, this still isn't working. I am very new to rails. Is it possible that it's because in my "versions" model (created for paper_trail) already has "change" defined as:   
`def change
    create_table :versions do |t|
      t.string   :item_type, :null => false
      t.integer  :item_id,   :null => false
      t.string   :event,     :null => false
      t.string   :whodunnit
      t.text     :object
      t.datetime :created_at
      t.datetime :updated_at
    end
    add_index :versions, [:item_type, :item_id]
  end`

Comment: Also, I'm using RubyMine as an IDE, which I find very helpful.