# Rails 4 x paper_trail: track which attributes are updated and display their new value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, versioning, records, paper-trail-gem

In my Rails 4 app, I am using [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) to track changes made by users on the records of the `Post` model:

```
# post.rb
has_paper_trail :on => [:update, :destroy]
```

A `post` `belong_to` a `calendar` and a `calendar` `has_many` `post`, so I display the changes made to posts in a dashboard located in the `calendar` `index` view:

```
<div id="my_changes">

  <% if @versions.any? %>

      <% @versions.each do |version| %>

      <% version.reify ? post = version.reify : post = Post.find_by_id(version.item_id) %>

      <p>
        <strong>
        <% if version.whodunnit.to_i === current_user.id %>
          You
        <% else %>
          <%= User.find_by_id(version.whodunnit).first_name %>
          <% end %>
        </strong> <%= conjugate(version.event) %> the post "<%= post.subject %>" in the <em><%= link_to Calendar.find_by_id(post.calendar_id).name, calendar_path(id: post.calendar_id) %></em> calendar <span id="update_time_ago">— <%= time_ago_in_words(version.created_at) %> ago.</span></p>

      <% end %>

  <% else %>

    <p>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up" aria-hidden="true"></span><br/>There is no change to your posts yet.<br/>
      As soon as you update your calendar, a history of your changes will appear here.          
    </p>

  <% end %>

</div>
```

This is working fine.

What I would like to achieve now — and I can't figure out how — is not only to display which post has been updated, but also which attribute of the post has been updated and its value.

For instance, instead of:

> User_1 updated the post "Test post" in the Test calendar — 3 days ago.

I would like to have something like:

> User_1 updated **the date / time / subject / copy / of** the post "Test
>   post" **to NEW_POST_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE** in the Test calendar — 3 days ago.

—————

**UPDATE**: I did read `paper_trail`'s documentation, in particular the *[Choose attributes to monitor](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#choosing-attributes-to-monitor)* section, but this does seem to explain how to achieve what I am trying to achieve.

—————

**UPDATE 2**: I understand that what I am looking for may actually be explained in the *[Diffing versions](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#diffing-versions)* section of the documentation.

So, I guess in my `index.html.erb` view, I could do something like:

```
post.versions.last.changeset
```

But then, how can I extract from there the information that I am interested in, eg: only the attribute that was updated, and its new value, and not the `updated_at` attribute, that I cannot `ignore` with `paper_trail` since I still want to know when the post was updated?

—————

**UPDATE 3**: in [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473183/paper-trail-show-diff-between-versions), @Maysam suggests:

> With this behavior enabled, it is reasonably simple to get
>   `object.versions.map{|v| [v.created_at, v.changeset]}` and then
>   iterate over that structure to render your change log.

I am not sure I understand how I can actually iterate over that structure in my case: any suggestion?

—————

Can I actually achieve that with paper_trail?

Comment: Please try to make this question shorter so it is more useful for other people. Thanks!

Comment: I would be happy to, but it is not easy to find the right balance in terms of length, since I am often asked to provide more code when I try and post short questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .. I would like to .. display .. which attribute of the post has been updated and its value.

Per the documentation on [Diffing Versions](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#diffing-versions):

> .. to diff adjacent versions .. add an `object_changes` text column to your `versions` table .. PaperTrail will store the changes diff .. in each update version. You can use the `version.changeset` method to retrieve it.

So, once you've done that, try adding

```
= debug post.versions.last.changeset
```

To your view. After that, [if you know how to work with hashes](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html) in ruby, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually where I am now. I am trying to figure out a way to deal with the different scenarios where users edit one attribute, several attributes, etc.